# Tibble silently changes recycled difftime variables

Tags: r, tidyverse, tibble

If a `difftime` variable is included in a tibble, and the specified number of observations is equal to the other variable(s), then the class of the variable is maintained.

```
tibble::tibble(a = c(1,2), b = as.difftime(c(1,2), units = "hours"))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a       b
  <dbl>  <time>
1     1 1 hours
2     2 1 hours
```

However, if the specified number of observations in the `difftime` variable is a proper factor of the number of observations in the other variable, so that the `difftime` variable is recycled, then the class of the variable silently changes to `numeric`:

```
tibble::tibble(a = c(1,2), b = as.difftime(1, units = "hours"))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2     1
```

Does this difference in behaviour occur because `tidyverse` users are encouraged to use the `period` or `duration` objects provided by `lubridate` to specify times, rather than base R's `difftime` objects? Or is this an unintended bug?

The same issue occurs when using `tibble::data_frame`, and `dplyr::data_frame`, although I believe these may be deprecated in the future.

To be clear, the following calls do not silently change the class of the time-type variable:

```
tibble::tibble(a = c(1,2), b = lubridate::as.period("1H"))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a            b
  <dbl> <S4: Period>
1     1     1H 0M 0S
2     2     1H 0M 0S

tibble::tibble(a = c(1,2), b = lubridate::as.duration("1H"))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a                b
  <dbl>   <S4: Duration>
1     1 3600s (~1 hours)
2     2 3600s (~1 hours)
```

Comment: It's a bug, as `tibble::tibble(a = c(1,2)) %>% mutate(b = as.difftime(2, units = "hours"))` works fine. [File an issue.](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues)

Comment: This raises an even weirder question: `data.frame(a=c(1,1), b=as.difftime(1, units="hours"))` does not recycle column `b`. But `data.frame(a=c(1,2), b=as.difftime(c(1, 2), units="hours"))` will work. This, to me, is a very odd behavior.

Comment: @Abdou whay very odd? data.frame don't recycle that's all.

Comment: @agstudy: yes, they do. In `data.frame(a=c(1.4,4),b=1)`, the vector `b` gets recycled.

Comment: @alistaire Done. Apologies for the delay.

Comment: @Abdou Indeed! Although that's a base R issue ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing stems from something quite peculiar with the vector recycling process during dataframe creations. As you already know, objects passed to the `data.frame` function should have the same number of rows. But ***atomic vectors*** will be recycled a whole number of times if necessary. This raises the question as to why the following does not work:

```
dff <- data.frame(a=c(1,2), b=as.difftime(1, units="hours"))
```

The code above raises the following error:

> Error in data.frame(a = c(1, 2), b = as.difftime(1, units = "hours"))
>   :    arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 1

It turns out, the reason this does not work is because a vector of `difftime` objects is not recognized as an atomic vector. You can check with the following:

```
is.vector(as.difftime(1, units="hours"))
```

This returns:

```
[1] FALSE
```

As result, when the `data.frame` function tries to recycle the column `b`, it checks first if the column is in fact a vector (with `is.vector`). Since that returns `FALSE`, the recycling does not proceed; and hence the error returned.

So, the ensuing question is: ***why not just convert column b with `as.vector`?***

This would have actually been a good idea, expect that `as.vector` ***removes all attributes***, including names, for the resulting vector. You can see that with the following:

```
as.vector(as.difftime(1, units="hours"))
```

returns:

```
[1] 1
```

All the properties of the `difftime` object got lost during the coercion process. This leads me to think that the `tibble::data_frame` function actually uses `as.vector` somewhere along the process of generating the `data_frame`. As a result, we see the following behavior:

```
data_frame(a=c(1,2), b=as.difftime(1, units="hours"))
```

returns

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2     1
```

I guess the conclusion is the same as the one reached by @agstudy: to maintain the `difftime` object, you may have to use `list` for column `b` as follows:

```
tibble::tibble(a = c(1,2), b = list(as.difftime(1, units = "hours")))
```

I hope this proves, in some way, useful.

Comment: I've marked this as the answer because it clearly explains why the bug exists. Submitted on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that `tibble` encourages the use of `lubridate` ( even if I encourage you to use it ) do deal with date like types , But it is more an issue of how are vector are created internally when you recycle. In fact you can reproduce the same recyclying behavior when you play with `c` and `list`. For example using `c` you will lose typing :

```
c(as.difftime(c(1), units = "hours"),1)
### Time differences in hours
### [1] 1 1
```

But using `list` will keep the time difference type :

```
list(as.difftime(c(1), units = "hours"),2)

# [[1]]
# Time difference of 1 hours
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2
```

Applying `list` with tibble , you "conserve" the class type:

```
tibble::tibble(a = c(1,2), 
               b = list(as.difftime(c(1), units = "hours")))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
# a          b
# <dbl>     <list>
#   1     1 <time [1]>
#   2     2 <time [1]>
```

But this is hardly manipulated later. Better to use `lubridate` in this case.